# The transform orientation after pressing 'g' and 'z' doesn't match 'Normal' transform orientation

Tags: transforms, normals, transform-orientation

I've rotated the mesh to a position that no longer matches the global axis orientation but still want to transform my selection at right angles.

I have transformation selection set to 'normal', the z-axis becomes horizontal (which is ok I guess, as long as I can move in that direction.) but when I press 'z' to constrain my movement along that axis it locks it to the traditional z-axis vertical movement.

I can manually transform respective to the 'normal' transformation mode by grabbing the arrows but I want to input specific transformation values which is impossible with manual dragging.
[image]

Comment: try gzz to move along local z axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as batFINGER says, the combination <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> move object in local Z axis.

Second, why you said

> I want to input specific transformation values which is impossible
>   with manual dragging.

Did you tried? Click and hold on the axis, and enter specific value from keyboard while you holding the mouse button.